# Problem in python3.3.2+

Tags: 13.10, python, python3

I am using Ubuntu 13.10.I have 2 versions of python.Python2.7.6 and python3.3.2+.(I don't know what is the '+' sign)Whenever I open python 3.3.2+ and type print "hello." .I get the invalid syntax error.Whereas in python2.7.6.I have no problem.please can anyone help me out?

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html - there are differences in syntax between python 2 and 3, such as `print` now being a function rather than a statement. `print("hello")` is the python 3 syntax to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The print statement is gone in Python 3 and was replaced with a print Function.

Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3